# Methods for vertically aligning a div not working

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-tables

I have this layout I'm trying to arrange. First I laid it out using a table, where I was able to make everything go where I wanted to. Sort of a 4-corners idea where each box was touching at the center like a grid. The upper-left box was stuck to the top of it's element but I was able to bring it down using the `vertical-align`.

However, I realized that if I wanted a fluid layout and the ability to "break down" the layout so that each block becomes it's own block element, I'd have to switch from a `table` design to a `div` design. After wrestling with it for a few hours, I managed to man-handle it into what I need for standard, large resolution screens (I haven't tried to shrink it down yet). But that stupid upper-left box is still stuck to the top of it's element and I can't figure out how to bring it down.

I've tried make the `div` before it in a position: relative, and then make the table `position: absolute` and then `bottom: 0px`, that didn't work.

I've tried the new `display: table-cell; Vertical-align: bottom`; thing I've never seen before, that didn't work.

I've tried `position: relative; top: 50%`; that didn't work (I know that would have technically only centered it, but I was just trying to make it move)

I can't remember what else I've tried but it's more than a little crazy that it would take THIS much effort just to vertically align a div, don't you think?

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do. Theoretically Upper Left Block should sit on the bottom of it's div, but it doesn't. This is just one example of things I've tried.

```html
<div style="border: 3px solid blue; display: table; height: 200px; width: 75%">
  <div style="display: table-row; border: 3px solid green;" >
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%; display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom;">Upper Left Block</div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 50%; display: table-cell;">Upper Right Block</div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-row; border: 3px solid orange;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%; display: table-cell;">Lower Left block</div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 50%; display: table-cell;">Lower Right Block</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me make this div behave?

**NOTE**: The object in **Upper-Right-Block** is an image of inconsistant height, which is setting the height for the row because it's taller than the content in the **Upper-Left-block**, so I cannot set a padding-top to **Upper-Left-Block** to fix my issue.

**Edit**: I've gone back and simplified my page to re-try the `Absolute Position` method, and for reasons unknown, it worked. I can get the info in the Upper-Left-Block to sit on the "bottom" of the div element accounting for the 20px padding down there. BUT!! It has messed up the width of my main div. The whole container is supposed to be 780px. Once I implement the `Absolute Position` thing, it shrinks the whole thing by about 30px, and I can't seem to make it expand again. It seems like a small thing, but it's messing with some other layout elements that I don't want to shrink anymore, otherwise I think they'll be hard to read.

I even resized my containing div to 1000px before implementing the Absolute Positioning, and it ***still*** shrunk everything down to about 750px. Why is it doing this and how do I fix it?

Here is where I am now:

```html
<div style="width: 1000px; margin: 100px auto;">
    <div style="width: 100%; position: relative;">
        <table style="width: 49%; float: left; position: absolute; bottom: 25px;">
            <tr><td>Table Data Here</td></tr></table>
        <img id="image" style="width: 50%; float: right; margin-bottom: 20px;" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-h-c-507-736-10.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; position: relative; clear: both;">
        <table style="width: 49%; float: left;"><tr><td>Table Data Here</td></tr></table></table>
        <table style="width: 49%; float: right;"><tr><td>Table Data Here</td></tr></table></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**FINAL EDIT**: Ok, I finally figured it out. I went with `position: absolute; bottom: 0px;` It wasn't working before because I hadn't set the div it was sitting in to `position: relative`. And then it was messing with my layout. It was shrinking it and I couldn't expand it back and I couldn't figure out why. Then I read that I needed to define the size of the parent div if I wanted the div with absolute position to remain the size I wanted. So we're all good here. Thanks to everyone who responded.

Comment: Some code would be nice. I cant really use Jedi mind tricks to move your upper left grid and snap it into its place.

Comment: Jedi mind tricks would be awesome though! ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: @sai Sorry, I had limited characters and i don't know how to add code boxes like I've seen other people do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help . basically as you are editing the question , you have this sort of menus on the top of that box that has a big bold B a slanted italicised I etc. Thats the features you are going to need

Comment: what about padding? This sounds like a job for padding-top padding-bottom

Comment: @sai Thanks, I JUST figured out how to do this. Hopefully this will help someone help me figure this out.

Comment: @gerdi This probably WOULD work, if not for the fact that the object in the upper-right block changes height, so setting an exact padding wouldn't work, as it wouldn't provide the consistent look I'm after.

Comment: @ShirleyDodson When does it change height? Are you using media queries . Besides that, you CAN use percentages in padding values

Comment: @gerdi What I mean is that different images of different heights go in that corner. How would you use padding to move the element in Upper-Left-Block to the bottom? Since the height changes, I would have to use `padding-bottom`. But I can't seem to get this element to budge with either % or px.

Comment: You should go to [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) and write this thing out properly and then go [here](http://lorempixel.com/) to get an image to show us what you are struggling with.